# cryptic comment in jdk source: // HD, Section 2-1

Tags: java, comments

i just stumbled onto this comment.

```
    public static int lowestOneBit(int i) {
    // HD, Section 2-1
    return i & -i;
    }
```

in the 1.5 java source.
what does this comment mean? is it a reference to a book? a spec?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

HD probably refers to [Hacker's Delight](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201914654) by Henry S. Warren. Indeed, this formula appears on page 11, section 2-1.

Comment: Agreed. The documentation for java.lang.Long tells us »Implementation note: The implementations of the "bit twiddling" methods (such as highestOneBit and numberOfTrailingZeros) are based on material from Henry S. Warren, Jr.'s Hacker's Delight, (Addison Wesley, 2002).«